# MS-ACCESS SQL Union Query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, union

When entering the SQL language for a union query pulling data from an excel workbook what is the correct code to have the union query select data from a specific tab in the excel workbook? Any advice or help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use an inline query pointing to external source which the underlying Jet/ACE SQL engine can do for Excel workbooks, Access databases, even text files (txt/csv).

Below assumes Excel workbook is latest format (.xlsx) and begins in A1 cell with defined column headers and same number of columns/types as rest of union query.

```
SELECT t1.* FROM 
myAccessTable t1

UNION ALL

SELECT t2.* FROM
[Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\Excel\Workbook.xlsx].[mySheetName$] t2
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes perfect sense and is very helpful. Your explanation gave me another idea I hadn't thought of. In my case I am importing the excel file into the tables and creating a duplicate table to protect the data. I can import the excel file directing access to create a table from each unique tab on the excel file and then create the union query joining all tables and records that I need.